# Using JavaScript to make flash content transparent

Tags: javascript, flash, menu, transparent

I am using this JavaScript to embed my flash file in a webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/swfobject.js">//</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="files/swfaddress.js">//</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="files/facebook.js">//</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var assetsFolder = 'assets';
      var mobileFolder = 'mobile';

      var changeURL = function(){
        if(document.getElementById('hrefMobile'))document.getElementById('hrefMobile').href = dir+mobileFolder+'/index.html';
        if(document.getElementById('hrefSEO'))document.getElementById('hrefSEO').href = dir+assetsFolder +'/seo/toc.html';
        delete changeURL;
      }
      if (document.addEventListener){
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", changeURL, false);
  } else {
    document.attachEvent("onDOMContentLoaded", changeURL);
  }


      function afterLoad(){ 
        checkPage(); 
        setFocusOnFlash(); 
          }

      function setFocusOnFlash(){ 
            var f=swfobject.getObjectById('content'); 

            if (f) { f.tabIndex = 0; f.focus(); } 
          }
          function getURLParam()
          {
          var returnObject = {};
          var href = window.location.href;
          if ( href.indexOf("?") > -1 )
          {
          var param = href.substr(href.indexOf("?"));
          var arrayParam = param.split("&");
      returnObject['assets'] = assetsFolder;
          for ( var i = 0; i < arrayParam.length; i++ )
                    {
                        var value = arrayParam[i].split("=");
                        returnObject[value[0]] = value[1];
                    }
            }
            return returnObject;
        }
        var dir = "./files/";

         var getURI = function(){
                var URIArray = document.location.href.split('/');

                 URIArray.length = URIArray.length-1;
                var URIstr = URIArray.join('/');

                URIArray = null;

                var URIarr = dir.split('/');
                URIarr[0] = URIarr[0]=='.'?'':URIarr[0];
                var dirStr = URIarr.join('/');

                URIstr = URIstr+dirStr;

            return URIstr;
            }



          var swfName = "flippingbook.swf?rnd=a920e3f104e299e21a8f93f76594fff6";

          var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
          platform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase(),
          UA = ua.match(/(opera|ie|firefox|chrome|version)[\s\/:]([\w\d\.]+)?.*?(safari|version[\s\/:]([\w\d\.]+)|$)/) || [null, 'unknown', 0],
          mode = UA[1] == 'ie' && document.documentMode;

          var Browser = {
          extend: Function.prototype.extend,
          name: (UA[1] == 'version') ? UA[3] : UA[1],
          version: mode || parseFloat((UA[1] == 'opera' && UA[4]) ? UA[4] : UA[2]),
          Platform: {
          name: ua.match(/ip(?:ad|od|hone)/) ? 'ios' : (ua.match(/(?:webos|android|bada|symbian|palm|blackberry)/) || platform.match(/mac|win|linux/) || ['other'])[0]
          },
          Features: {
          xpath: !!(document.evaluate),
          air: !!(window.runtime),
          query: !!(document.querySelector),
          json: !!(window.JSON)
          },
          Plugins: {}
          };

          if(Browser.Platform.name == 'android' || Browser.Platform.name == 'ios') window.location = dir+mobileFolder+"/index.html";
          if(Browser.Platform.name == 'webos' || Browser.Platform.name == 'bada' || Browser.Platform.name == 'symbian' || Browser.Platform.name == 'palm' || Browser.Platform.name == 'blackberry') window.location = dir+assetsFolder+"/seo/page1.html";

          var flashvars = getURLParam();

          var params = {baseURI: getURI(), base: dir, allowFullScreen: true, allowScriptAccess: "sameDomain", quality: "high", scale: "noscale",bgcolor:"FFFFFF"};
          var attributes = {align: "middle"};

          swfobject.embedSWF(dir + swfName, "content", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", dir + "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);</script>
```

and

```
  <body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height:100%; width:100%;" onLoad="afterLoad()">
```

I would like to make the flash animation transparent when I load this page in an iframe, so it doesn't cover the drop down menu ...

Answer (score 0):

Set the flash' to use `wmode` `transparent`. That will make it respect the z-ordering of your elements.

Replace your current params line with this:

```
var params = { baseURI: getURI(), 
               base: dir, 
               allowFullScreen: true, 
               allowScriptAccess: "sameDomain", 
               quality: "high", 
               scale: "noscale", 
               bgcolor:"FFFFFF", 
               wmode:"transparent" 
             };
```